# What is the command PUSH29 010..00 in solidity compiled bytecode?

Tags: solidity, bytecode

If you take a look to the bytecode of several contracts compiled from solidity you can notice that in the first ".data" basic block there is this command:

```
PUSH29 0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

For instance, this simple contract contains this command:

```
pragma solidity^0.4.24;
contract test {
   function f(int8 x) public pure returns (int8) {
     return x+1;
   }
}
```

What is the purpose of this command?